# Converting contents of HtmlTextWriter to a string

Tags: .net, asp.net, htmltextwriter

I have a third party tool that creates an img tag through code using HtmlTextWriter's RenderBeginTag, RenderEndTag & AddAttribute methods. I want to get the resulting HTML into a string. 
I tried the reflection method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008551/htmltextwriter-to-string-am-i-overlooking-something) but I get a  error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.HttpWriter' to type 'System.IO.StringWriter". The  InnerWriter type of the HtmlTextWriter is of type HttpWriter.

Any ideas on how to copy the output html into a string?

**Addition:** code from third party control

```
protected override void Render( HtmlTextWriter output )
  {
  .....
  output.AddAttribute( HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, src );
  output.RenderBeginTag( HtmlTextWriterTag.Img );
  output.RenderEndTag();
                <-- What is the HTML now? Maybe look in OnPreRenderComplete event?

  }
```

Comment: What does the `HtmlTextWriter` come from?

Comment: It's passed to the overridden render event of the third party control.

Answer (score 12):

```
StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter h = new HtmlTextWriter(w);

ctl.RenderControl(h);

return w.ToString();
```

Obviously, you got to close the connections properly.  But it's roughly this; I had done this for unit testing, but I apologize, I don't have the exact code in front of me at the moment.

HTH.

Comment: I don't have any controls. It's just an img tag created in code. Looking for solution starting from an existing HtmlTextWriter which uses an HttpWriter.

Comment: Ok, then, could you post some code as to how you are working with the HttpWriter or HtmlTextWriter, so I can better advise?

Comment: See my addition in the question.

Comment: Ok, you can use my technique on any control to just get the HTML; you can have this code in the page code-behind even... if all you are looking for is to get HTML.  If you want to override the HTML, you could try inheriting from their class, and overriding the render process.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
        output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, src);
        output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Img);
        output.RenderEndTag();

        string html = output.InnerWriter.ToString();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would hold the type which is HttpWriter.

Comment: Hmm...it works quite nice for me.
http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/1568/57208217.png

Comment: This works only if you created HtmlWriter yourserlf and passed StringWriter to it. Here you are calling StringWriter.ToString().